# Recursive function to parse JSON data from NSArray - Not returning correct number of results

Tags: json, core-data, recursion, nsarray

I'm attempting to parse category data from a web store served in JSON Array format via REST into core data on iOS. Before I begin inserting to core data, i'm simply just logging the output to screen and keeping count of the results to check everything is ok.

**The Problem** In my test data set I have **152** categories, however I am only getting a 'Final counter' of **141** outputted to the log?

I've looked and looked at the recursive function and believe its ok, therefor I think the problem lies somewhere in the findSubcategoriesForCategoryID function?

Any feedback on the problem would be most grateful as this has kept me up for hours now.

Example JSON data returned from Web Service:

```
Node: {
    categoryID = 259;
    categoryTitle = "Engine Parts";
    parentID = 0;   // Parent ID of 0 indicates a root category
}
Node: {
    categoryID = 300;
    categoryTitle = "Camshafts";
    parentID = 259; // Parent ID indicates this category is a subcategory
}
Node: {
    categoryID = 317;
    categoryTitle = "Kent Camshafts";
    parentID = 300;
}
```

The following methods are what I have so far in my application.

```
/**
 *   Kickstarts parsing operation
 */
- (void)parseCategoriesData:(NSArray *)downloadedData {
    NSMutableDictionary *fakeCategory = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [fakeCategory setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"categoryID"];

    int counter = 0;
    [self recursiveFunction:downloadedData parentCategory:fakeCategory counter:&counter];

    NSLog(@"Final counter = %d", counter);
}

/**
 *   Recursive function to traverse the passed NSArray
 */
- (void)recursiveFunction:(NSArray *)array parentCategory:(id)parentCategory counter:(int *)i {    
    NSArray *subCategories = [self findSubcategoriesForCategoryID:[[parentCategory valueForKey:@"categoryID"] intValue] categoryData:array];

    for (id object in subCategories) {
        NSLog(@"Node: %@  depth: %d",[object description], *i);
        *i = *i + 1;
        [self recursiveFunction:array parentCategory:object counter:i];
    }
}

/**
 *   Returns an NSArray of subcategories for the passed categoryID
 */
- (NSArray *)findSubcategoriesForCategoryID:(int)categoryID categoryData:(NSArray *)categoryData {
    NSIndexSet *indexsForFilteredCategories = [categoryData indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return (BOOL)([[obj valueForKey:@"parentID"] intValue] == categoryID);
    }];

    return [categoryData objectsAtIndexes:indexsForFilteredCategories];
}
```

Comment: You should log the entire resulting array, not the count. Then the error should become self-evident.

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive function looks OK, but it is rather convoluted, so only a test can guarantee that it really works for all special cases.

If I understand your algorithm correctly, you start from the top and go down to the items that have the present id as the parent id. It follows, **that you might have parent ids that do not exist as category ids**.

This is quite easy to test:

```
NSArray *allIDs = [downloadedData objectForKey:@"categoryID"];
NSArray *allParentIDs = [downloadedData objectForKey:@"parentID"];

for (NSNumber *x in allParentIDs) {
   if (x.intValue==0) continue;
   NSArray *allChildren = [allIDs filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
     [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self = %@", x]];
   if (allChildren.count == 0) {
      NSLog(@"There are no category ids for parent id %d.", x.intValue); 
   }      
}
```